# Wpf Volumetric effect?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, mask, light

I would like to know if WPF support 3D Volumetric Effects like "spotlight (sort of smoke effect like in nightclub)"

Typically, I would like to set a brush (sort of mask or filter : color + shape ) and see "light ray" from light source to any obstacle..

i'm not sure wpf can handle that, if it doesn't what's the best software to do that, it should be real time and get parameter from a C# application

if it does, have you any example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally handled as "fog". OpenGL and DirectX support it, but WPF doesn't. You can do it on your own if you want to badly enough, but IMO, it's not a good idea -- if that's what you want, WPF really isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: @Bgnt44: Offhand, I'm not sure.

Comment: Is it possible to make it more simple ...


I could use 3D cone but only if i can put some brush at the bottom face of my cone and "extrude" it to the top , i will set alpha depend of the brush ( black = 0% and white = 50 % ) and a spot light inside the cone , 

if my cones are longer than my "room" ?

Comment: Does WPF or XNA shape can be autoluminescent

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The "fog" in OpenGL, DirectX and XNA is distance fog. It allows you to obscure things further away from the camera (this was used in the old days for a smooth fade-out to obscure distant objects, so they need not be rendered, for performance). To achieve volumetric lighting effects (like light rays), you need to create and render actual geometry for the beam. The built-in light and fog in OpenGL, DirectX and XNA do not support this.

Comment: ok thanks, so i can do it with wpf as well as d3d, opengl or others .?